# Different font color for not selected tab's tab-label

Tags: css, javafx

I try to style Java FX 8 `TabPane` component via CSS. Currently I'm struggling with different font color for selected and not selected `tab-label`. At the end, I want selected tab to have white font color, and not selected tab to have black font color. Unfortunately, I don't know how to refer to not selected or only to selected `tab-label`. I tried `.tab-label:selected` but it didn't work. I also tried something as `.tab:selected > .tab-label` but again, didn't work.

Below is CSS code I wrote so far and preview of the TabPane.

```
#tabPane {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#tabPane .tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#tabPane .tab {
    -fx-background-color: #d0d0d0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 5 10 10 10;
}

#tabPane .tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #202020;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}

#tabPane .tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
}
```

[image]

PS Mentioned `TabPane` was modified only by above CSS code. There are no other modifications. Thus, no additional code.

Comment: Please share full code with codepen.io link or any other...?

Comment: There is no need to share full code, because there is no additional code refering to the mentioned `TabPane`. I've provided everything which is refered to its style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
#tabPane .tab:selected .tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: black ;
}
```

should work. It may be important to have that after your `#tab-pane .tab-label` rule.

Comment: Yes, it worked when putting your lines after `#tabPane .tab-label` rule. Thank you very much for help.